# MongoDB querying references with additonal information

Tags: mongodb

I am storing data of organizations in the following document structure:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
    "name": "NASA",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5629f0b20fe85c57ed459913"),
            "level" : "organization_lead"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5629ff550fe85c57ed459914"),
            "level" : "team_member"
        }
    ]
}
```

Users are in another collection and look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5629ff550fe85c57ed459914"),
    "email" : "bob@email.com",
    "firstname" : "Bob",
    "lastname" : "Green",
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to get a list of user documents belonging to a specific organization?

If I had only the _id's in the users array I would just pass that array to another query to get the users but what should I do in this situation? Or is there a better way to have a reference that has additional information?

Comment: You could [denormalize your data](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3), or [maybe not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156395/denormalization-of-data-in-mongodb). Without "embedding" (denormalization), you'll have to perform a second query to look up the users; you could do this by building an array of user IDs to search and then: `{$in:userIDArray}` where `userIDArray = [ObjectId('...'),ObjectId('...'),...]`.

Comment: How do your documents in the "users" collection look like? What is the expected result? please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33333746/edit) to your question to add those informations.

Comment: I added the user collection document structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** method of the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** cursor for the organisation collection to iterate over, access the documents in the loop and call the **[`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne)** method to get the full user document of each user _id, as in the following example:

```
db.organisation.find({ "name": "NASA", "users.0": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var updatedUsers = doc.users.map(function(u){
        var user = db.users.findOne({"_id": u._id});
        user["level"] = u.level;
        return user;
    }
    doc.users = updatedUsers;
    printjson(doc);     
})
```

Comment: Your first query will not return any document because of the way the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays) operator works.

Comment: I see you edited your post but it doesn't make thing better. You shouldn't use `$where` I guess you know why.  use the dot notation instead `"users.0": { "$exists": true }`.  But IMO  the question is unclear because I don't know the expected result.

Comment: @user3100115 Thanks for the correction. Would have been helpful if the OP had sufficient info to kill the speculation nonetheless I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use populate,

```
db.organisation.findOne({ "name": "NASA"}, function(err, response) {
 db.Users.populate(response.user, {'path': _id, 'select': 'firstname lastname email'}, function(err, populatedUserData) {
  console.log(populatedUserData);
 });
});
```

Output will be,

```
[{
"_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
"name": "NASA",
"users" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : [{
                   "_id" : ObjectId("5629f0b20fe85c57ed459913"),,
                   "email" : "laurem@email.com",
                   "firstname" : "laurem",
                   "lastname" : "Ipsum"
                 }],
        "level" : "organization_lead"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : [{
                   "_id" : ObjectId("5629ff550fe85c57ed459914"),
                   "email" : "bob@email.com",
                   "firstname" : "Bob",
                   "lastname" : "Green"
                }],
        "level" : "team_member"
    }
]}]
```